# I am trying to figure out logic to produce top 200 results for all categories in the IN command. (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

So the code I have the following code as of now:

```
select top 200 employees,phone_no,address,job_code
from from employee
where code IN  ('BA', 'QA', 'BI')
```

So the result I am looking to produce is
Top 200 results for `BA` and then Top 200 Results for `QA` and Top 200 results for `BI`. So total records it should populate would be 600. The current code would populate 200 only. I can do union commands but its lengthy. Looking for effective solution in this case scenario.

Comment: `TOP 200` is a little vague without an `ORDER BY` clause. Does that matter?

Answer (score 4):

While I think that `Union` is the appropriate way to solve this, you could probably also use Window Functions to get a row number partitioned by `code` and then restrict that in an outer query:

```
SELECT employees,
  phone_no,
  address,
  job_code,
FROM
    (
     select employees,
        phone_no,
        address,
        job_code,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) as code_rownumber
     from from employee
     where code IN  ('BA', 'QA', 'BI')
    )subquery
WHERE subquery.code_rownumber <=200
```

There's a good chance this will take longer than a `SELECT TOP 200... UNION SELECT TOP 200... UNION SELECT TOP 200...` since a `row_number()` will need to be done for each record, and only after that is it limited to less than 200.

Also, it's peculiar that you are wanting the top 200, but you don't specify your sort order. In the window function above, if you want to specify how you sort, you would do so like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY job_code DESC) as code_rownumber
```

Where we sort by job_code in descending order for the numbering of each record within each `code` partition.

Comment: THIS IS SUPER PERFECT. I learned something new. This is doing exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks! Super 7 star answer! You RoCK! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Break your query into 3 sub queries and union the results.
For example, if i have to select Top 2 records for Cateogry in 'A' and 'B'
The query would be,

select top 2 ProductID1,Revenue1 from ProductTotals1 where Category IN ('A') 
union
select top 2 ProductID1,Revenue1 from ProductTotals1 where Category IN ('B')

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question statement includes "I can do union commands but its lengthy."

Comment: Use a query which has the least performance cost. The length/ complexity of the query dosen't matter. And to your answer to the post The ORDER BY needs to sort the resultset which may take long if it's big.

Comment: Your "answer" provides a solution which the OP had already considered and hoped to avoid based on _their_ preference for something more elegant, hence it is a best a comment. My comment regarding `ORDER BY` was directed to the OP to determine whether it would affect the correctness of results. If it is required to obtain the correct results the OP may have to accept the additional resources required. Length, complexity, portability, maintainability, performance (CPU, memory, I/O, ...), ... are all valid metrics for the OP to consider.

Comment: I am sorry, your comment is best!